# mysql information_schema empty and not populating

Tags: mysql, information-schema, mysql-5.7

Running WAMP localhost server With php 5.6.18 and MySQL 5.7.11 
In project that im working on now i need to get some column data form `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` table, but `information_schema` DB is completely empty - 0 rows for every table in this DB 
For additional information - I have like 10 differnet DB on this MySQL, some are imported some are made from scratch in phpmyadmin.
So im completely lost - tried to google but no luck.
Maybe i miss something essential and trivial like some configuration of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Execute this query:

`mysql> SHOW GRANTS;`

This will show you that either you are not logging in as the user you intend to use, or that this user lacks permissions on the tables in question.

In this case, the user may have no permissions at all.  MySQL has a special permission called `USAGE`, which may seem slightly deceptively named if you aren't familiar with what it means.  It means you can "use" the server -- that is, you can log in.  But that is all it means.   If you possess **only** the `USAGE ON *.*` privilege, this means you have permission to log in to the server, but no permissions on anything else.

The `information_schema` is integrated with the permissions system.  You can't see information about database objects for which you don't have permissions.  An empty `information_schema.columns` table suggests a permissions issue for the user you are using to connect to the server.

Comment: i have this response - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' so what does it mean that i cant use and see information_schema data? how to change this permission?

Comment: This user should be able to see everything.  From here, from exactly the same place where you got this result, does information_schema.columns still appear empty?  What about `SHOW DATABASES;`?

Comment: i see that comments dont allow asterix - its asterix point asterix between ON andTO

Comment: SHOW DATABASES shows all my databases including information_schema

Comment: Actually, * and ` both have markdown meanings in comments.  * is italics and ` is code.  I believe they can be escaped with backslashes but have never worked out exactly how.  Ah, backslash added before each ` or * produces `\*\`.\`\*\`.

Comment: Okay, from here, can you select from information_schema.columns?

Comment: SELECT  * FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` ->returns table structure because ther is no rows

Comment: That's unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this may be issue when you copy and paste the database's folders in mysql folder. Don't copy that way. The best way to export the databases using "export" command in "phpmyadmin" or use "mysqldump" command in mysql command line client to copy the data or export data from one to another.It will generate "yourdata.sql" file  at the last , You can import that data using "export command in "phpmyadmin" . In your method is successful for "MyISAM" database driver in  mysql. Modern mysql servers default database driver is "InnoDB" and it not success in when copy the database data folder on to another machine. If you have copy of previous copy of the databases from the old machine, try to export the "yourdata.sql" file using export method in "phpmyadmin" web interface.

Comment: i haven`t moved any folders in MySQL folder, and im always importing databases via phpmyadmin import function, and all databases that i have imported came from phpmyadmin exported mysql dump files - .sql

Comment: Have you tried the command line client in mysql . If the databases and tables can be viewed using mysql command line client there is no problem. You can continue your development process. Sometimes the error will be in wamp installation.

Comment: databases and tables are in MySQL and are ok, problem is that `information_schema` is empty - there is no information about my other databases in MySQL that i have imported and made from within phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry, this answer is very incorrect.  `information_schema` is entirely internal.  It can't be imported or exported and it has no corresponding files.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot , if this answer is incorrect what is the correct answer ?

Comment: Actually, I misread part of your answer.  I mistakenly thought you were saying "information_schema" had been improperly copied, which is not possible.  I apologize for the downvote.  I will attempt to remove it.  Your answer still may not explain the problem, but it is not incorrect for the specific reason I thought it was.

Comment: I can't remove the downvote, unless the answer is subsequently edited; votes can only be recalled within 5 minutes after they are cast.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot No worries , god bless you man :-D , Don't try to up vote it , I'm not a expert like you!

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I've removed my answer , So you can give a better soultion . Hats off man!

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that @Drew but it seemed a little sketchy to do it myself. Thanks. -1 removed.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for editing and voting my answer. I didn't expect that . What we want is give the right thing to  who may need help to resolve a problem. I believed that sharing knowledge is a must!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for editing and voting my answer. I didn't expect that . What we want is give the right thing to  who may need help to resolve a problem. I believed that sharing knowledge is a must!

Comment: I can't take must credit for anything my friend, except for a small spacebar touch :p

Comment: @Drew Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I transfer/shifted my mysql folder to other location.
And configured DB to point Mysql folder accordingly.

However, Information_schema was not getting updated though rest DB queries were running fine.I could't find proper solution but the way around was from mysql editor (like workbench) do inspect schema.

You will get an option in bottom to 'Information Outdated' and then click on Analyze table. You will find that Information_schema start calculating correct size and other details.